# c# Store a single value

Tags: c#, arrays

Newbie question:

Let's say I have an int array that can store 10 values

How do I take a user input 1 time to only fill 1 bracket and then stop untill a new user stores a value? I've only ever know how to fill arrays in loops, but I'm guessing no loops are used to just store 1 value.

Comment: `MyArray[0] = MyAwesomeValue` where 0 is the index of the element you want to change?

Comment: You store values in an array by index: `arr[0] = input`. But as for "stopping until a new user stores a value", well it's hard to know how to interpret that! The answer might be quite complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int[] arr = new int[10];

    int i = 0;//counter
    while(i<arr.Length)
    { 
        Console.Write("Enter an integer: ");
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arr[i]))
        {
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter to continue!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou didn't enter an integer!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you mean, but this doesn't continually ask the user to provide an input, it just asks once:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[9];

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value: ");
        arr[0] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a `List<>`, then when you know you're ready, you can convert it into an array. With a List it's easy to add items.

```
int[] GetUserInput()
{
    var list = new List<int>();
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value or just press enter to indicate you are done.");
        var s = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) break;
        list.Add(int.Parse(s));
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```